# NoReverseMatch at /posts/post/18/comment/ Django Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've been getting this error, and I couldn't seem to fix it.
Here is a screenshot of it: [erros image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng4n0.png)

Here my view's.py:'

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from posts.forms import PostForm, CommentForm

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from . import forms
from . import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")


class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "posts/user_post_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.post_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("posts").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.post_user.posts.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["post_user"] = self.post_user
        return context


class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(
            user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )


class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    # form_class = forms.PostForm
    fields = ('message','group')
    model = models.Post

    # def get_form_kwargs(self):
    #     kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    #     kwargs.update({"user": self.request.user})
    #     return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")
    success_url = reverse_lazy("posts:all")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Post Deleted")
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)



def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(models.Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('posts:single', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'posts/comment_form.html', {'form': form})



def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('posts:single', pk=comment.post.pk)



def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('posts:single', pk=post_pk.pk)
```

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

import misaka

from groups.models import  Group

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts",null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "posts:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        unique_together = ["user", "message"]



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

here's my post_detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load staticfiles%}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="footer, address, phone, icons" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Raleway|Signika|Signika+Negative" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ask Uptown</title>
    <style media="screen">


    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }


    body{
      font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
      background-color: #E6ECF0;
    }

    .h12{
      text-align: center;
    }

    .hero{
      position: relative;
      width: 1200px;
      margin-left: 500px;
      margin-top: 0;
      top: 190px;
    }

     .banner{
      color: white;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 170px;
      left: 125px;
    }

    .buttons{
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-left: 490px;
    }

    .btn{
      border: 1px solid white;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .buttons a:hover{
      background-color: #cdc9c9;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .about{
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      color: #F4F7F8;
    }
    .about h1{
      color: black;
      margin-top: 60px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 35px;
    }

    .paragraph-about{
      color:black;
      font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
      margin-left: 70px;
      margin-right: 60px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .section{
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px;
      background-color: #F4F7F8;
    }


    .card-pic{
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .card-pic h4 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .card-pic p{
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 12px;
    }


    .card-pic-two{
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 100px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .card-pic-two h4{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .card-pic-two p{
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 12px;
    }

    .card-pic-three{
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 150px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .card-pic-three h4{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .card-pic-three p{
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 12px;
    }

    .main-nav {
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 45px;
    }

    .main-nav li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .main-nav li a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
      font-size: 19px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .main-nav li:hover a {
      border: 1px solid white;
    }

    .main-nav li a:active {
      border: 1px solid white;
    }


    .footer-distributed{
      background-color: #292c2f;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      font: bold 16px sans-serif;

      padding: 55px 50px;
      margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    /* Footer left */

    .footer-distributed .footer-left{
      width: 40%;
    }

    /* The company logo */

    .footer-distributed h3{
      color:  #ffffff;
      font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .footer-distributed h3 span{
      color:  #5383d3;
    }

    /* Footer links */

    .footer-distributed .footer-links{
      color:  #ffffff;
      margin: 20px 0 12px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-links a{
      display:inline-block;
      line-height: 1.8;
      text-decoration: none;
      color:  inherit;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
      color:  #8f9296;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0;
    }

    /* Footer Center */

    .footer-distributed .footer-center{
      width: 35%;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
      background-color:  #33383b;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 25px;
      width: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 42px;
      margin: 10px 15px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 38px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center p{
      display: inline-block;
      color: #ffffff;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin:0;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
      display:block;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height:2;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
      color:  #5383d3;
      text-decoration: none;;
    }


    /* Footer Right */

    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
      width: 20%;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
      line-height: 20px;
      color:  #92999f;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
      display: block;
      color:  #ffffff;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-icons{
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color:  #33383b;
      border-radius: 2px;

      font-size: 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 35px;

      margin-right: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .footer-distributed{
      position: relative;
      top: 200px;
    }

    /* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

    @media (max-width: 880px) {

      .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
      }

      .footer-distributed .footer-left,
      .footer-distributed .footer-center,
      .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
      }


    }

    .twitter{
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
    }


    .facebook{
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
    }

    .instagram {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }

    .icons{
      margin-top: 20px;
    }


    .adress{
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .email{
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }

    .phone{
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .adress-sec{
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .phone-sec{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .logo-text{
        color:  #ffffff;
        font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 27px;
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 27px;
    }

    .logo-text span{
      color: #5383d3;
    }


    .backgr{
      background-color: #7F7F7F;
      height: 13vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }



    header{
      background: src(.backgr);
    }

  .no-ans{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

.add-comment{
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #B388EB, #8093F1);
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  left: 1100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: 800px;
  top: 75px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<header>

<div class="backgr">
    <nav class="" role="navigation" id="navbar">
          <div class="">
            <div class="logo">
              <a class="logo-text" href="{% url 'home' %}"><h3>Uptown<span>Ask</h3></span></a>
          </div>


              <ul class="main-nav">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                      <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Stuck? Ask A question</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'groups:all' %}">Groups</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">My Post History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Log out</a></li>
                {% else %}
                      <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'groups:all' %}">Groups</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" >Log in</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" >Sign up</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>

          </header>

          <section>

            {% block post_content %}
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% include "posts/_post.html" %}
            </div>
            {% endblock %}

              <a class="add-comment" href="{% url 'posts:add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk%}">Answer This Question</a>

          </div>


          {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
          <br>
              {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}

                      {{ comment.created_date }}
                      {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                          <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                          <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
                      {% endif %}

                  <p>{{ comment.text|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
                  <p>Posted by: <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong></p>

              {% endif %}
          {% empty %}
              <p>No comments posted.</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>




          </section>


    <footer class="footer-distributed">

    <div class="footer-left">

    <h3>Uptown<span>Ask</span></h3>

    <p class="footer-links">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    ·
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    ·
    <a href="#">About</a>
    ·
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </p>

    <p class="footer-company-name">Ask Uptown &copy; 2017</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-center">

    <div class="adress-sec">
    <p class="p-adress">Address: Tripoli Street, Algeria Road, Mirdif Area - Dubai, United Arab Emirtes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="phone-sec">
    <p>Phone: 04 251 5001</p>
    </div>

    <div class="email-sec">
    <p class="p-email"><a href="mailto:rayanza3eem1234@gmail.com">Email: Uptownschool@gmail.com</a></p>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer-right">

    <p class="footer-company-about">
    <span>About the company</span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectateur adispicing elit. Fusce euismod convallis velit, eu auctor lacus vehicula sit amet.
    </p>

    <div class="icons">

    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="twitter" ></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="facebook" ></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="insta.png" alt="Instagram" class="instagram" ></a>

    </div>

    </div>

    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find the fix for this advanced error in django. Could anyone plz help.

I've been trying to solve it but could not, each comment is suppose to be link to a comment.

Thanks

Comment: Your URL pattern (which you haven't shown) takes `username` and `pk`, but you are only passing `pk` when you `redirect`. You could either remove `username` from the URL pattern, or include the username when you reverse the URL with `redirect`.

Comment: Please cut your post down to the minimum necessary. There's no reason to post all that CSS, for example.

Comment: Still can't figure it out, i added a username argument

Answer (score 1):

The error points to

```
return redirect('posts:single', pk=post.pk)
```

Which may be causing the error because it expects you to pass a `username` argument in addition to the `pk`.